# Does HAProxy bydefault protect itself from tcp syn flood attack

Tags: security, tcp, load-balancing, haproxy, denial-of-service

Does HAProxy by default protect itself from TCP SYN flood or DOS attacks? If not then how can I protect HAProxy load balancer from these attacks?

Comment: BTW, this question belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't (if you have something simple like the [examples](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#2.5) they provide or follow most tutorials out there) but [this](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/use-a-load-balancer-as-a-first-row-of-defense-against-ddos/) HAProxy blog covers SYN flood attacks and some DoS attacks.

You could harden your system against SYN attacks at kernel level with the following settings in sysctl:

```
administrator@HAProxyUbuntu:~$ sysctl -a
  net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
  net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
  net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 1024 
  net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 3
```

The max_syn_backlog value can be passed in from HAProxy by using the backlog parameter:

> In order to protect against SYN flood attacks, one solution is to increase
>   the system's SYN backlog size. Depending on the system, sometimes it is just
>   tunable via a system parameter, sometimes it is not adjustable at all, and
>   sometimes the system relies on hints given by the application at the time of
>   the listen() syscall. By default, HAProxy passes the frontend's maxconn value
>   to the listen() syscall. On systems which can make use of this value, it can
>   sometimes be useful to be able to specify a different value, hence this
>   backlog parameter.

http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4.2-backlog